# cannot use realtek ethernet controller

Tags: networking, drivers, 16.10

in 16.10 i have a ethernet controller as listed below. but I cannot turn it on or configure it. any ideas on what to do.

```
00:02.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890/RD9x0/RX980 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI Express GFX port 0)
00:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890/RD9x0/RX980 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI Express GPP Port 0)
00:05.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890/RD9x0/RX980 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI Express GPP Port 1)
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890/RD9x0/RX980 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI Express GPP Port 3)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 40)
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 SMBus Controller (rev 42)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) (rev 40)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller (rev 40)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge (rev 40)
00:14.5 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller
00:15.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB700/SB800/SB900 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 0)
00:16.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:16.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 5
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208 [GeForce GT 710] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK208 HDMI/DP Audio Controller (rev a1)
***02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 11)***
03:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1042A USB 3.0 Host Controller
04:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1042A USB 3.0 Host Controller
06:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ethernet device is probably using the r8169 driver, which is buggy. You need to install the **r8168-dkms** driver (and **dkms**).

Start Synaptic. Click the RELOAD icon. Click the SEARCH icon and enter **r8168-dkms**. Enable for installation that item in the results pane. Click the APPLY icon. Reboot.

Let us know how you make out.

Cheers, Al

Comment: ok thank you for responding so quickly, now i see it as an unmanaged connection. when i reboot i cannot get out when the ethernet cable is connected. if I remove the cable I can get out on wifi connection.

Comment: There is no way to add the connection in the settings pane. when i run ip link the result is; 1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp2s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 14:dd:a9:4f:7b:1c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp6s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 80:a5:89:6d:82:4b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Comment: ifconfig show; enp2s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 14:dd:a9:4f:7b:1c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 377  bytes 54164 (54.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 1  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 204  bytes 28028 (28.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 43  base 0xe000

Comment: How/where is the ethernet cable connected? One end to your computer, the other end to where? Next, in terminal, type `lsmod | grep -i r816` and lets see if it responds with `r8169`. If it does, go ahead and install `r8168-dkms` using the wireless connection that you can make. Then retest the ethernet connection. Cheers, Al

Comment: OK I dont know if this was fixed with the official release of ubuntu. But I am going to make a comment on this. When I install Ubuntu, it all works fine, when I go to add or install ubuntu-gnome-desktop the havok is wreaked on the wired network connection. It causes the enp2s0 connection to drop off and is no longer if listed as a network option. I tried this both installing ubuntu-gnome and installing ubuntu-gnome-desktop and got the same result. I tried another distro with gnome 3.22 and did not get this problem, so it is definitely something in the ubuntu-gnome files.

Comment: to heynnema, i reinstalled prior to your answer, sorry, I would of loved to try that, I am thinking there is something wrong in the install scripts for ubuntu-gnome. But prior to this, yes the mod was in lsmod when I ran it.

Comment: I think this is a bug, but cannot use apparmor to report it, because of the way it comes up. any ideas of how to report this another way.

Comment: When you reported this problem, were you running on a pre-release of 16.10? If so, then we both wasted a lot of time. I hope that you're running on the final stable release now. The r8168-dkms driver thing probably is still valid either way. Just check to see if you're running the r8169 driver now. Cheers, Al

Comment: I did install a daily build release when this happened but I updated to the full version. I am going to try and install the full version and as a secondary boot and then try to install the ubuntu-gnome-desktop again. I will report what happens; do you need me to do anything specific while doing the install. All this was done on the 13th the official release day so the daily build should of been the same as the final release.

Comment: You never answered my question about how your ethernet  cable is connected, and the output of lsmod. See 5 comments back. Cheers, Al

Comment: the problem came up when I had the cable connected without the cable connected wifi worked. I have not had the chance to try the install again yet, but will do tomorrow. I am nervous about adding the gnome desktop to the working system, but I am creating a small partition to try the install again.

Comment: OK I seem to have the problem figured out along with the use of the nvidia driver. I installed gnome-ubuntu first, then installed ubuntu-desktop, switched to lightdm, delete the .Xauthority file installed the newest nvidia driver for 16.10 and rebooted all came up normal. see,ed to be the easiest way to get past all the problems. Solved

Comment: What does any of this have to do with your original question about an ethernet controller that didn't work? You wasted my time.

Comment: Sorry you think I wasted your time, I have used Ubuntu for a long time, but never had a weird problem like this come up. If I install Ubuntu 16.10 first and then ubuntu-gnome-desktop, and finally cairo dock, I lost my ethernet connection when gdm3 was the display manager (did this three times), however using lightdm as the display manager when I reinstalled it the problem went away.  I dont know why I have never seen a problem like this before. As for the nvidia driver I got that worked out at the same time so it was a comment.

Comment: It **was** a very strange problem, with lots of twists and turns. Glad you finally got it going to your satisfaction. Cheers, Al

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but changing the way I installed the files made a difference and using lightdm as the display kept me from loosing my ethernet connection. So as long as I kept lightdm as the window manager I did not loose my ethernet connecton as for heynnema sorry I wasted your time.